# Get full CPU name without WMI

Tags: winapi, wmi

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the full processor name (as shown in Control Panel | System) without using WMI? I'm guessing there's some unmanaged call you can make.

WMI does the job, but I'm finding it intermittently crashes or locks up on some computers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just be able to check the registry:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\ProcessorNameString should give it to you

Here is some example code:

```
var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\");
var processorName = key.GetValue("ProcessorNameString");
Console.WriteLine(processorName);
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this just returns some numbers. Can I get a the full CPU name?

Comment: This produces "AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4600+" for me.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer - I originally suggested the  GetSystemInfo win32 call, but that takes some work to parse - the registry way should be easier :)

Comment: This produces "AMD Turion(tm) X2 Dual Core Mobile RM-70" for me.

Comment: @Eric Are You saying that GetSystemInfo win32 call also returns data that can be parsed to CPU name?